# Generating an histogram with Matplotlib using a dataframe for x and y

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm generating a simple line chart with Matplotlib, here is my  code:

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#131722',dpi=155, figsize=(8, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,0), facecolor='#131722')

for x in OrderedList:
    rate_buy = []
    total_buy = []

    for y in x['data']['bids']:
        rate_buy.append(y[0])
        total_buy.append(y[1])

    rBuys = pd.DataFrame({'buy': rate_buy})
    tBuys = pd.DataFrame({'total': total_buy})

    ax1.plot(rBuys.buy, tBuys.total, color='#0400ff', linewidth=0.5, alpha=1)
    ax1.fill_between(rBuys.buy, 0, tBuys.total, facecolor='#0400ff', alpha=1)
```

Which gives me the following output:
[image]

And here is the data i used in the dataframe:

```
     buy
0   9611
1   9610
2   9609
3   9608
4   9607
5   9606
6   9605
7   9604
8   9603
9   9602
10  9601
11  9600
12  9599
        total
0    3.033661
1    3.295753
2    3.599813
3   22.305765
4   22.987476
5   30.975145
6   39.492845
7   42.828580
8   46.677708
9   49.533740
10  50.925840
11  61.396243
12  61.921523
```

I want to get the **same** output of the image, but with an histogram chart or whatever it's similar to that, where the height of the column on the y axis is retrieved from the `total` dataframe and the x axis position is retrieved from the `buy` dataframe. So the first element will have position `x=9611` and `y=3.033661`

Is it possible to do that with Matplotlib? I tried to use `hist`, but it doesn't allow me to set both the x and the y axis

Comment: Your values of *buy* are coming decreasingly, you have to reverse X axis. In face here the graph is done perfectly with it orders the values of X after mapping them. Try `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas uses matplotlib as well](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html), and the API is very easy once you have the dataframe.

Here is an example.

```
d =    {
         'buy':[
             9611,
             9610,
             9609,
             9608,
             9607,
             9606,
             9605,
             9604,
             9603,
             9602,
             9601,
             9600,
             9599
         ],
         'total':[
             3.033661,
             3.295753,
             3.599813,
             22.305765,
             22.987476,
             30.975145,
             39.492845,
             42.828580,
             46.677708,
             49.533740,
             50.925840,
             61.396243,
             61.921523
         ]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df.sort_values(by=['buy']) #remember to sort your x values!
df.plot(kind='bar', x='buy', y='total', width=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that i need the bars to be one near another, not spaced, so that they produce a similar output to the image i attached

Comment: Just pass  `width=1` to the plot function. It works exactly as matplotlib. The same goes for the style, you can use the matplotlib styles or define your own.  I will update my example.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, in my case i have two different dataframes, how can i merge the two into one df?

Comment: With Pandas.DataFrame.merge()/concat()/join() it depends what you want. Check the Pandas docs! If you need help, please add the relevant input and expected output in your question.

Comment: No problem, i managed to do that! Here is what i did: ax1.df.plot(kind='bar', x='buy', y='total'), but i got the following error: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'df'

Comment: Indeed, axes and data frames are two different things. you can pas your axis like this `df.plot(ax= ax1, ....)` Please, read the docs! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Comment: This works. Thank you a lot! Yes, i'm reading the docs! One last thing: what is the difference between using your method and using plt.bar()? Is it the same thing?

Comment: It is the same thing. Pandas uses matplotlib, it just adds some extra API on top of it. I like the Pandas API a bit more.